# JDBC Prepare Statement Parameter values

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, prepared-statement

Is there a way to use the Java.sql.PreparedStatement or com.microsoft.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement to retrieve the parameter values without executing the SQL using statement.execute() ?
My requirement is to construct a sql in Java and pass the sql as a parameter to stored procedure.

I just want to do the type conversion of Data,Number and String parameters from Java to SQL Server types without executing the SQL.

Comment: You should be able to implicitly convert using ResultSet res = statm.executeQuery(sql); String val = res.getString(1); This has been converting types cleanly for me in most cases.

Comment: How would I get thr resultset without calling the execute?

Comment: res = statm.executeQuery(sql);

Comment: I do not want to leave application layer and make a call to Db. Executequery will call DB which I don't want

Comment: If you are preparing the statement you are executing it, otherwise you can't get any values back. Could you maybe elaborate how you are planning to run your statement without calling the backend, maybe add some code?

Comment: I am trying to create dynamic sql in the code and execute the sql via stored procedure. The sql has to built completely in java first

Comment: I'm afraid it's still not at all clear what you are trying to accomplish, or what your actual question is.

Comment: I want to pass a sql like "Update Table Set Id=123 and Name='xyz'" as a parameter to a stored procedure. In the stored proc i will be executing that SQL using sys.sp_execute

Comment: Submit all your parameters as strings, which should implicitly convert numerics and dates.

Comment: yes. that's what I am doing just wanted to check if there is a better way as there is lots of stuff happening in SQLServerStatement class to handle types

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft do you have any suggestion please?